# IIS 7 404 redirect for virtual directories

Tags: iis-7, rewrite, directory, url, virtualization

we are in the middle of setting up a website and one of the developers has asked me a question im a little but stuck on.

basically we have a website that a user can visit and create there own "virtual" subfolder group.

so for instance, you would visit www.mydomain.com/index.aspx and signup a free account. At the end of this process this would give you a URL to your new website.

www.mydomain.com/yourwebsite/index.aspx

now the "yourwebsite" folder is done using URL rewritting from the asp.net application, it never exists on the website ever. my problem is that if the user decides to visit

www.mydomain.com/yourwebsite/ they get a 404 Page Not Found error, is there a way within IIS7 to resolve this, as in my eyes the behaviour is correct as the folder does not exist so IIS cannot find it to display the contents of it.

any advice would be appreciated.

Kris

Comment: Can you post how you are rewriting the URLs?  That may help in trying to come up with an answer.

Comment: according to our developer they are using an ASP component (Found here http://www.urlrewriting.net/149/en/home.html) to-do the re-writing, the rules for this are in the web.config, i have copied what i can from the web.config file below.

Comment: turns out the comment box is not large enough to take the web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem turned out to be our lack of experience with the URL ReWrite component that we were using.

Once the developers looked at the data in the web.config file closer they spotted an obvious problem with it, after correcting this it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added index.aspx as a default document within IIS on your website?  That is not included as a default document out of the box, you need to add it.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply, i have tried to add index.aspx into the base websites default documents section however this has no affect when trying the URL again.